# MySQL Performance: Single Object With Multiple Types - JOIN scenario

Tags: mysql, performance, oop

With the following type of table design:

http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/classTableInheritance.html

Let's use the following schema for sake of example:

```
CREATE TABLE `fruit` (
  `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `type` tinyint(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `purchase_date` DATETIME NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `apple` (
  `fruit_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `is_macintosh` tinyint(1) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `orange` (
  `fruit_id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `peel_thickness_mm` decimal(4,2) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


ALTER TABLE `fruit`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`id`);

ALTER TABLE `apple`
  ADD KEY `fruit_id` (`fruit_id`);

ALTER TABLE `orange`
  ADD KEY `fruit_id` (`fruit_id`);


ALTER TABLE `fruit`
  MODIFY `id` int(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT;

ALTER TABLE `apple`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `apple_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`fruit_id`) REFERENCES `fruit` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;

ALTER TABLE `orange`
  ADD CONSTRAINT `orange_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`fruit_id`) REFERENCES `fruit` (`id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Here, 'apples' and 'oranges' are types of 'fruit', and have unique properties, which is why they've been segmented out into their own tables.

The question is, from a performance standpoint, when performing a `SELECT * FROM fruit` query, would it be better to:

a) perform a `LEFT OUTER JOIN` on each typed table, i.e. `apple` and `orange` (in practice, we may be dealing with dozens of fruit types)

b) skip the joins and perform a separate query later for each `fruit` row in the application logic, so for a `fruit` row of type `apple`, `SELECT * FROM apple WHERE fruit_id=...`?

EDIT:
Regarding the specific scenario, I won't go into excruciating detail, but the actual application here is a notification system which generates notifications when certain events occur. There is a different notification type for each event type, and each notification type stores properties unique to that event type. This is on a site with a lot of user activity, so there will eventually be millions of notification rows.

Comment: This won't satisfy you but here goes: the query that does less work will perform better. Since you have no data, it's not possible to determine what's faster. TL;DR: insufficient information to come to a valid conclusion.

Comment: But a general rule is that joins will usually be better than performing lots of separate queries in a loop.

Comment: Instead of lots of separate tables for each type of fruit, consider using a single attribute-value table.

Comment: Get only data you need when you need it.  So if you need to display the subordinate data for apple, orange at the same time your displaying the fruit data, then get it all on a left join.

Comment: I updated the question with some of the details of my specific application. @Barmar, my concern with the `LEFT OUTER JOIN`s is that since only one of them will match on the key, it's going to result in a lot of wasted index seeks. Do you think an additional query per row is more expensive than, say, ~10 missed index seeks per row? I have considered using a single table, but due to the number of rows I thought that might be a waste of space due to all the empty reserved data columns.

Answer (score 1):

Have one table with columns for the 'common' attributes (eg, type='apple', purchase_date=...), plus one `TEXT` column with `JSON` containing any other attributes (eg, subtype='macintosh') appropriate to the row in question.

Or it might make more sense to have `subtype` as a common attribute, since many fruits have such (think 'navel').

What will you be doing with the "inheritance"?  It's great in the textbook, but it sucks in a database.  SQL predates inheritance, object-oriented, etc.

Comment: The JSON column is a good idea, but I do need to select on those columns, so that's out.

The actual application as mentioned in the edit is for a notification system based on different event types.

Comment: Have you checked out what is in MySQL 5.7 and MariaDB 10?

Comment: @Dan - you can perform a SELECT on JSON columns (although not by using SELECT keyword).

Comment: You can actually index some JSON fields in one case.